# simple asp.net search

Tags: asp.net, search-engine

I am trying to add a search box in my page, where I can search the database.

This is the code I have so far

```
Partial Class Search
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Select [Title]
FROM [Books]
WHERE ([Title].theName LIKE '%' )
RETURN

End Class
```

Basically I want the search to return any work that appears in the database or close to it.

Answer (score 1):

Well...  it looks like you have a lot of ground to cover based on your first attempt.  I think it would greatly behoove you to walk through some tutorials/videos on the very basics of data access in ASP.NET.  There is some really good stuff here:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/data

Look over some of the videos at the very bottom of the page "SQL Server 2005 Express for Beginners".  After that, I would recommend taking a look at the LINQ videos above that.

To more directly answer the question, I would recommend using a prepared statement/stored procedure if you want to use ADO.NET.  I'd be more inclined to hook up a LINQ to SQL DataContext and do something like:  `yourContext.TargetTable.Where(o => o.SearchField.Contains("string to search")`

Neither of those are going to make much sense until you get a basic footing in data concepts though.  Be aware this is something that can compromise your entire application if done wrong...

Comment: I have looked at  some videos but they very general, All i need is a simple search box on my page where it returns what ever is typed in the box as long as it exists in the database.

Comment: You didn't watch enough of them.  This is covered several times in the videos I linked you to.  "All you need" and "simple search box" clearly involve a bit more than you're trying to make it out to be seeing as you can't figure out how to make it work.  Do the research, try it out, ask questions if you get stuck, we'll get you through it.